# Memory occupied by individual key in Redis using Jedis?

Tags: java, memory, redis, jedis

How do we find memory occupied by individual key in Redis using Jedis?jedis.info("memory") provides only the total memory used by the redis server.

Answer (score 2):

After installing the redis-rdb-tools as described [here](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools#installing-rdbtools), we can use it to find out the memory used by a key.

finding out memory for a key from running redis.

```
redis-3.2.4 $ redis-memory-for-key -s localhost -p 6379 mystringkey
Key    "mystringkey"
Bytes    88
Type    string
redis-3.2.4 $ redis-memory-for-key -s localhost -p 6379 myhashkey
Key    "myhashkey"
Bytes    115
Type    hash
Encoding   ziplist
Number of Elements  2
Length of Largest Element 6
```

finding out memory for a key from a rdb file.

```
redis-3.2.4 $ rdb -c memory dump.rdb -k mystringkey
database,type,key,size_in_bytes,encoding,num_elements,len_largest_element

0,string,"mystringkey",88,string,13,13
```

finding out memory for all keys for a pattern.

```
redis-3.2.4 $ rdb -c memory dump.rdb -k my.*
database,type,key,size_in_bytes,encoding,num_elements,len_largest_element
0,list,"mylistkey",219,quicklist,7,6
0,sortedset,"mysortedsetkey",143,ziplist,6,5
0,hash,"myhashkey",115,ziplist,2,6
0,string,"mystringkey",88,string,13,13
0,string,"myhllkey",168,string,90,90

0,set,"mysetkey",452,hashtable,4,6
```

finding out memory for all keys for a pattern and exporting to a csv file.

```
redis-3.2.4 $ rdb -c memory dump.rdb -k my.* -f memory.csv
redis-3.2.4 $ head memory.csv 
database,type,key,size_in_bytes,encoding,num_elements,len_largest_element
0,list,"mylistkey",219,quicklist,7,6
0,sortedset,"mysortedsetkey",143,ziplist,6,5
0,hash,"myhashkey",115,ziplist,2,6
0,string,"mystringkey",88,string,13,13
0,string,"myhllkey",168,string,90,90
0,set,"mysetkey",452,hashtable,4,6
```

Comment: Cool, but this requires some sort of external tool, right? Perhaps adding the link to it would be good.

Comment: @ItamarHaber My Bad. Added the link to the utility.

Comment: @Anirudha please accept this as answer if it helps you.

Comment: @Abhishek thanks for the details, however I was looking for the implementation using Jedis. Please let me know if you find the solution in the direction.

Comment: @AnirudhaSant Using Jedis, solution: https://redis.io/commands/memory-usage

Answer (score 1):

As of Redis v4, you can call the [`MEMORY USAGE`](https://redis.io/commands/memory-usage) to obtain an accurate measurement of a specific key-value.

Looking at the Jedis javadocs (http://xetorthio.github.io/jedis/), I can't find a suitable wrapper method to invoke this but you should be able to use the `sendCommand()` method of the `Connection` class to work around that.

Answer (score -1):

From my answer here: [Is there a way to pass redis commands in jedis, without using the functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54301598/is-there-a-way-to-pass-redis-commands-in-jedis-without-using-the-functions/61968024#61968024)

```java
import redis.clients.jedis.util.SafeEncoder;
// ... Jedis setup code ...
byteSize = (Long) jedis.sendCommand(new ProtocolCommand() {
                                        @Override
                                        public byte[] getRaw() {
                                          return SafeEncoder.encode("memory");
                                        }}, 
                                    SafeEncoder.encode("usage"), 
                                    SafeEncoder.encode(key));
```

... please click on my original answer link above for more information about this as I'm not sure if SO would flag me if I just pasted it here completely.